# How can I track button click in google analitycs?

Tags: google-analytics, javascript, jquery, click-tracking, button

I had register my website in the google analytics and I had put the script in my default index like this :

```
<html>

<head>

    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="****************" />

    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-7**4*7***"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-7**4*7***');
</script>
</head>

<body>
...
<a class="" href="/Contents/Make-App">
    <div class="text">Make app</div>
</a>
...
<script src="/Content/assets/script/combined.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-*4**0**6-*"></script>

<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-*4**0**6-*');
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want if I click button "make app", it will be listed on Google Analytics. so I can see how many people clicked on that button

How can I do it?

Comment: @closetnoc What the solution?

Answer (score 5):

You are using gtag.js tracking code. Syntax for event tracking for gtag.js is:

```
gtag('event', 'action', {'event_category': 'category', 'event_label': 'label', 'value': value});
```

If it does not require a value, the parameter can be omitted.
Add it to your button using onclick eg

```
<button onclick="gtag('event', 'click', {'event_category': 'button', 'event_label': 'make app'});">Make App</button>
```

Ref: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events